# Is this possible exchange sever 2010 migration to 2016 on this environment?

Tags: exchange-2010, migration, exchange-2016

I need to install Exchange 2016 on new Windows 2016 server and then need to migrate Exchange 2010 to 2016

I have my DC and Exchange 2010 on the server together

Here is the image that explains the environment:

[image: environment]

Is that possible to connect to DC which that also has Exchange 2010 when I install Exchange 2016? Can we do a migration migration like that image?**

I've searched about migration but almost Exchange Server environment that I've searched is separated from  DC like this

[image]

Comment: If there is any progress, welcome to share it. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing in your image that would prevent things from working as long as your AD environment fulfills any requirements Exchange 2016 may have on the AD schema/functional level.

In fact from a perspective of security and recommended configuration it's a good thing to separate non-AD-related functionality from your domain controllers.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the document ***[Installing Exchange on a domain controller](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/installing-exchange-on-a-domain-controller-is-not-recommended-exchange-2013-help)***, installing Exchange on a domain controller will affect the following points:

•   **AD split permissions isn’t supported.**

•   **The Exchange Trusted Subsystem USG is added to the domain admin group. And all Exchange Servers in the domain will be granted domain administrator rights.**

•   **Performance of Exchange Server and AD.**

•   **Make sure the Exchange Server is installed on a global catalog server. According to your situation, you could bypass this point.**

•   **System shutdown will take considerably longer.**

•   **Demoting a DC to a member server isn’t supported.**

•   **Running Exchange on a clustered node that is also an Active Directory domain controller isn’t supported.**

In addition, as **Mikael** said, there is nothing would prevent things from working in your image, so you could continue to migrate your Exchange Server 2010 to 2016. To learn more details about the steps of migration, you could refer to the link: https://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-for-migrating-exchange-server-2010-to-2016-part-5/. Hope everything goes well with you!

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I still try and I hope it goes well too :)